# PHP include from external server

Tags: php

I want to use the PHP "include" function to include a file from a different domain than my main script, and use variables from the main script in the included file.

Something like this:

*index.php:*

```
<?php
  $hello = "Hello";
  $world = "World";
  include "http://example.com/myfile.php";
?>
```

*myfile.php* (from a different domain)

```
<?php
  echo $hello . " " . $world;
  // Should output "Hello World"
?>
```

Will this work, or does it depend on the server settings/permissions?

Comment: Don't do this unless you are absolutely sure that the file you are including is trustworthy. Even then, this gives me the jitters. If you actually have control over both domains you're safer having two copies of the included file. If you're just trying to get some data from another domain do the job properly and write a small API to do it.

Comment: No this won't work. When you include it, you don't get the source of it. You just get the output of the `myfile.php`, which would be an error because neither $hello or $world is defined in that script. You'll need to change `.php` to `.phps` or make sure the other domain isn't running parsing that file as PHP.

Comment: @MikeW, I'm doing this to include a common help document in several Joomla installations (using a custom Joomla module). I do have control over both domains. I like the idea of creating a small API, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several answers point out, `allow_url_include` has to be enabled, and that's not an option in my case. I ended up doing this:

index.php:

```
<?php
  $hello = "Hello";
  $world = "World";
  echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/myfile.php?hello=$hello&world=$world");
?>
```

myfile.php (from a different domain)

```
<?php
  $hello = $_GET['hello'];
  $world = $_GET['world'];
  echo $hello . " " . $world;
  // Should output "Hello World"
?>
```

It works fine for what I need it to do, but I'm sure the solution can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php):

> **Using remote files**
>
> As long as allow_url_fopen is enabled in php.ini, you can use HTTP and FTP URLs with most of the functions that take a filename as a parameter. In addition, URLs can be used with the include, include_once, require and require_once statements (since PHP 5.2.0, allow_url_include must be enabled for these). See [Supported Protocols](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) and Wrappers for more information about the protocols supported by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It will work depending on whether or not `allow_url_include` is enabled in `php.ini`. Otherwise you can try the hacky way of doing it by replacing the current `include` line with:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/myfile.php');
```